# FxCop or other util to require inline docs in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, documentation, fxcop, require

I'm starting a new project; trying to be more strict than previous ones. I've set warnings as errors in the build I've added FxCop to PostBuild. The one last thing on my list os require people to add inline docs for all classes/non-private methods/properties.

Is there a custom FxCop rule or another exe I can run in the post build to check? I've having a hard time finding something, which is surprising.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler throw out warnings for documentation missing on non-private members/classes, which would turn to errors with your settings? Or doesn't vb.net do that? The C# compiler does. Anyway, +1 for really trying to make things better in the next project.

Comment: Only in C#. I really hate that MS keeps doing things like that different between C# and VB.NET projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo:  http://www.ookii.org/software/xmlcommentchecker/

Comment: No the next trick is to figure out how to turn its warnings into a build breaking failure.

Comment: In my case, recompile the source to output error in the console instead of warnings. Then the build fails.

Answer (score 0):

The VB.NET compiler doesn't help much in this regard as I've only ever seen it issue a warning for something like `<param name="foo">...</param>` when you don't have a parameter called "foo" in the function, but nothing at all for missing tags which is annoying.

The method I use on my projects is to use the build log from [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) and grep it for the warnings it spits out since they're faily easy to match (they all begin with something like "Warn: ShowMissingComponent:" and it will issue a warnings for all sorts of missing tags in your code.